# hypothesis testing of sum of bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ has Bernoulli distribution with probability of success $p$. On the basis of a random sample of size $n$ it is proposed to reject the null hypothesis $p=1/2$ if
$$
         X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n \ge \frac{3}{8}\text{ or }\le\frac{5}{8}
$$
for $n=5$ find the level of significance.

Comment: Please note the $\LaTeX$ formatting I did to your question.

Comment: thnx sir..@Andreas Caranti....can u pl answer my question?

Comment: Not me, not my field.

Comment: This sounds like an easy one.  $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$ takes on values $0,1,2,3,4,5$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{32}, \frac{5}{32},\frac{10}{32}, \frac{10}{32}\frac{5}{32}\frac{1}{32}$ respectively and so the null hypothesis is _always_ rejected.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You're asked to find the significance level $\alpha$ which is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis given that it is true.